# How to activate/deactivate plugins for svgo

Tags: plugins, command-line-interface, svgo

**I have installed svgo like so:**

`[sudo] npm install -g svgo`

**Downloaded the default config from repo:**

https://github.com/svg/svgo/blob/master/.svgo.yml

**Edited the config like so:**

  `...
  - minifyStyles
  - convertStyleToAttrs
  - cleanupIDs: false
  - removeRasterImages
  - removeUselessDefs
  ...`

**Replaced the default like so:**

`svgo --config=custom.yml`

**As described here:**

https://github.com/svg/svgo#cli

**I run SVGO like so:**

`svgo test.svg test.min.svg`

*...but the plugin I've deactivated (cleanupIDs) is still active.*

I've tried to deactivate other plugins too (i.e. removeTitle) but there is no effect on my output file.

Appreciate some guidance!

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the plugin you want `enabled` or `disabled` by name, directly in your command line interface:

```
svgo --enable={cleanupIDs} test.svg -o test.min.svg
```

This will ensure that the named plugin(s) will be enabled **if they are disabled by default, see help screen**:

```
svgo -h
```

will produce this help screen: https://github.com/svg/svgo#cli where you can find this piece of information:

> ```
> --disable=PLUGIN : Disable plugin by name,
> --enable=PLUGIN : Enable plugin by name,
> ```

```
svgo --show-plugins
```

will actually show which plugins are available and which are **disabled by default**.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [Configuration section of the SVGO README](https://github.com/svg/svgo#configuration) for how to configure plugins today.

Since v2.0.0, there are two supported ways to configure this:

- Create a file called `svgo.config.js` in current working directory.
- Create a file *somewhere*, and pass the path to the `--config` command-line argument.

A minimal configuration looks like:

**`svgo.config.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'preset-default',
    'reusePaths'
  ]
};
```

To use it from the same directory as the config:

```bash
svgo {{path/to/vector.svg}}
```

To use it from a different directory from the config:

```bash
svgo --config {{path/to/svgo.config.js}} {{path/to/vector.svg}}
```

To enable a plugin that is not in the default preset, include it in the plugin array like the example above.

To disable a plugin from the default preset, pass the `override` parameter, and set the plugin to `false` like the following:

**`svgo.config.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'preset-default',
      params: {
        overrides: {
          removeViewBox: false
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Reference: [SVGO documentation for how to disable a default plugin](https://svgo.dev/docs/preset-default/#disable-a-plugin)

### SVGO v1.x.x

In versions before v2.0.0, plugins were toggled through command-line arguments or a YAML file rather than the SVGO config file.

- [Release notes for v2.0.0.](https://github.com/svg/svgo/releases/tag/v2.0.0)
- [Commit that removed old style of configuring plugins.](https://github.com/svg/svgo/commit/d761decc0e7026d45c0ca81812c1cd7a8ab334f0)

[See VeRo's answer for how to configure SVGO pre-v2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271093/6277798)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to specify a parameter at the beginning of the custom.yml `full: true`